# Apparent error with "equal" arrow style in tikz-cd -- problem with Xpdf renderer

Tags: tikz-cd

I've reduced the problem to this test case:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=0.5em]
A & B & C \ar[d, equal] & D \ar[d, equal] \\
E & F & G \ar[d, equal] & X \\
I & J \ar[d, equal] & 41 & L \\
X & 31 & O & P
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

The observed output is:

[image: Output of test case after processing by pdflatex]

The symptom is that the lines from `C` to `G`, from `G` to `41`, and from `D` to `X` should be double lines (arrow style "equal") but are drawn as single lines (arrow style "dash").  In addition, there should be a line from `J` to `31`.

From tweaking the test case, it appears that the specific text of the matrix elements `X`, `41`, and `31` and the option `column sep=0.5em` are significant in triggering the error.

I am using texlive-tikz-cd-svn49201-39 and texlive-latex-20200327-30 on Fedora 34.  Significantly out of date, but it seems like this is a matter of basic functionality.

Comment: Can you check with another PDF viewer/renderer? I've noticed lines vanishing when zooming in and out with the built-in viewer of TeXstudio (which isn't the best) and a more consistent visualization with evince. I've tested your MWE in Overleaf (where I can set TeXLive 2020 manually) and all four lines appear correctly.

Comment: Seeing compilation result in `sumatra` or in `Adobe Reader` looks fine.

Comment: I have compiled the code with TeX Live 2019 and 2020, but can't reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Checking more carefully, it definitely is a rendering problem rather than a TeX problem.  I see the problem with xpdf (4.04 on Fedora 34), but it is inconsistent depending on the magnification.  I do not see the problem with (on Fedora 34) GNU Emacs (27.2, probably using GhostScript gs 9.55.0 to render PDFs) or Evince (GNOME Document Viewer 40.5) or (on MacOS 12.6.4) Preview (11.0), Safari (16.4), or (111.0.1 64-bit).